# Why does Ctlr+P bring up randomly different print windows in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

So I'm doing nonsense with SendKeys (Duplex printing >_>), and for some reason, Ctlr+P (seemingly) randomly brings up two different dialogs - the normal one, and something the "old" one.

[image: "Old" version]

[image: "New" Version]

Why is this? And what can I do to consistently get the same dialog?

Excel 365, build 1926

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: 365, build 1926

Comment: Please add this info to the body of the question. Also, am I correct to assume that without doing anything else in between, you're saying that you press CTRL-P once and one of these dialogs comes up, and at other times the other shows?

Comment: The first (old style) dialog looks like Firefox's Print dialog, which AFAIK is also a generic one. If you're using Excel as a cloud application it's possible that it does not always intercept your Ctrl+P command and lets your browser handle it instead. You could see if it produces a different result by trying to print them into a PDF or something like that.

Comment: I'm using Excel on the desktop